# PHP is reporting errors but i can't find any

Tags: php, sql, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a working website coded in codeigniter and PHP suddenly started to report errors, for example

```
<?php
    $cats = array('7', '9');
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('posts');
    $this->db->where_in('posts.category_id',$cats);
    $this->db->where('is_slider=1');
    $this->db->where('visibility=1');
    $this->db->where('posts.status=1');
    $this->db->where('posts.created_at < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()');
    $this->db->order_by('created_at', 'DESC');
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows()){
        $primeras = $query->result();
    }
?>
<?php foreach ($primeras as $primera): ?>
    <div class="single-default-inner-news">
        <div class="news-image">
            <?php
            if($primera->post_type == "post"){
            ?>                                
                <a href="#" class="w-100"><img style="min-width:100%" src="<?= base_url() ?><?php echo $primera->image_big ?>" alt="image"></a>
            <? } ?>
            <?php
                if($primera->post_type == "video"){
            ?>
                <a href="#"><img style="min-width:100%" src="<?php echo $primera->image_url ?>" alt="image"></a>
            <? } ?>
                <a href="<?= base_url() ?><?php echo $primera->title_slug ?>" class="link-overlay"></a>

            <div class="news-content" style="padding-top: 15px; width:100%">
                <h2><a href="<?= base_url() ?><?php echo $primera->title_slug ?>"><?php echo $primera->title ?></a></h2>
                <p><?php echo $primera->summary ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And this is the error

> Message: syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH)

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `<? } ?>` -> make sure you have enabled short tag in PHP, try chang it to `<?php } ?>`

Comment: Every `if` closing needs to be `<?php } ?>` not `<? } ?>`.Closing the question as TYPO mistake

Comment: you guys are right, the hosting removed the short tags

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, hosting removed my short tags option in my php.ini